# Android SpeechRecognizer when do I get ERROR_CLIENT when starting the voice recognizer?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-glass

I am not sure about some documentation related stuff.

To sum up what I did and what I want to to: I managed to introduce **voice recognition** feature into an **Android** application that is running on Android 4.2 on a tablet, and it works ok. Now I want to port my application on **Google Glass** but unfortunately I get the following error when I **try to start the speech recognizer: error 5 -> ERROR_CLIENT**(Other client side errors). The message guides me to find other errors that not related to SpeechRecognizer object, but I don't get any in my logs, not even warnings. So my **question** would be: **When exactly do I get ERROR_CLIENT? and what should look the errors that block the recognizer to start?**

Thank  you! :)

Comment: You probably forgot Audio permission in your manifest.

Comment: No, not at all. When I don't have enough permissions I receive another code, and that is 9 not 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after a bit of pain I manage to solve my problem regarding my glass application.

**First of all I found that SpeechRecognizer only works when my glasses are connected to the internet!** Even so I still received from times to times ERROR 5. That was because I have a bad connectivity to the internet and from times to times my glass just disconnected from the internet without any notifications! I think this is an issue that must be solved for the next level of glasses. It just cannot disconnect from the internet without notifying you.

**So one of the causes for ERROR_CLIENT(5) on Google Glass is: not having internet connection**

Comment: *"because I have a bad connectivity to the internet"* could explain ERROR_CLIENT(5) on Android smartphones, too?

Answer (score 10):

I found this link that is the source code for producing the errors.

[SpeechRecognizer source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.java)

There are 7 places where a search found "ERROR_CLIENT"

Here's the log statements right before the ERROR_CLIENT is sent to onError

- Log.e(TAG, "no selected voice recognition service");
- Log.e(TAG, "bind to recognition service failed");
- Log.e(TAG, "startListening() failed", e);
- Log.e(TAG, "stopListening() failed", e);
- Log.e(TAG, "cancel() failed", e);
- Log.e(TAG, "not connected to the recognition service");

Of course you can find more info at the above link, but this should give you the general reasons why you'd get ERROR_CLIENT

Comment: Any idea why my Android Studio (2021.3) does not show those [Log.e(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74991194/2597758) messages in the Debug console?

Answer (score 1):

The error happens also if the **[Google search application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) has no permissions to the microphone**. In that case, the phone speech recognition service will be disabled and the ERROR_CLIENT error will be triggered for all apps (the above case was verified on a Samsung phone running Android 11)

Comment: I get this ERROR_CLIENT(5) despite (Google)[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox] app having the required permissions to the microphone. Verified. This happens sporadically, so I believe @IspasClaudiu's is the correct explanation in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I was using an **object variable** inside the **main loop**:

```
class SpeechRecognition implements RecognitionListener {
    private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;

    public void transcribe (Activity activity) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
            this.speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this.activity);
            this.speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this.listener);

            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)

            this.speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
        }
    }

    [...]
 }
```

Solution:

```
class SpeechRecognitionRunnable implements Runnable {
    private volatile SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
    private RecognitionListener listener;
    private Activity activity;

    public SpeechRecognitionRunnable (RecognitionListener listener, Activity activity) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this.activity);
        this.speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this.listener);

        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

        this.speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
    }

    public SpeechRecognizer getSpeechRecognizer() {
        return this.speechRecognizer;
    }
}

class SpeechRecognition implements RecognitionListener {
    private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;

    public void transcribe (Activity activity) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new SpeechRecognitionRunnable(this, activity)
    }

    [...]
 }
```

Comment: Nice! Could you explain a bit more about the root cause and your solution? By *"object variable"* are you referring to `Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)` ?

Comment: I think it was due to the `speechRecognizer` variable. Unfortunately, I don't really know why this fixed it. I was just happy that it did :)

Comment: Thank you. I am struggling now with the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74991194/2597758). Using the [stack trace approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74991194/2597758), I can forensically try to find out what caused it. It would be nice, though, to get that information during runtime, so that it can be passed to the end-user (after proper translation, of course).