# Android Speech Recognition on smartglasses Vuzix M300

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-contacts-api, vuzix

We are currently developing an application that needs voice interaction. The app is for the smartglasses Vuzix M300. We have tried their sample app for Speech recognition but it does not work as expected (some words are not always recognized).

After much effort and research, we have been able to install Google app and Google Now launcher to have Google Speech recognition services available in the glasses.

But after developing a very simple application just after calling

`speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);`

we get error "CLIENT_ERROR" on the "onError" event of the speechrecognizer listener.

We have search the whole net searching for this and have debug the application but as the [Android SpeechRecognizer when do I get ERROR_CLIENT when starting the voice recognizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995565/android-speechrecognizer-when-do-i-get-error-client-when-starting-the-voice-reco) states, there are 7 places where the ERROR_CLIENT is sent to onError but it is not sent from there, it is sent from the InternalListener and internal handler, with the handleMessage beeing MSG_ERROR (all this comes from the SpeechRecognizer.java class from the android.speech package.

So we are stucked and don't know where is this error coming from and why.

I hope anybody can help us.

If you need more information or code of the application (but it is very simple and it seems it has nothing to do with our code) ask for it.

Thanks a lot in advance

Regards.

Comment: Well, the error must be sent from one of the seven methods, unless you installed other APIs. When there's an error, the `SpeechRecognizer` class calls the `onError` method in `InternalListener`, which then sends `MSG_ERROR`.